# How can I enable gzip compression on WCF websocket duplex nethttpsbinding

Tags: wcf, websocket, .net-4.5

I would just like to enable gzip compression to the following binding.

Here is what I have in my config file currently.

```
  <netHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="MutualCertificateBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Binary">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
      <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" />
    </binding>
  </netHttpsBinding>
```

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789(v=vs.110).aspx) tcp, http, and https in WCF are all capable of compression as of 4.5, I'm on 4.5.2.

Keep in mind I'm actually using a WCF contract with a callback contract so duplex is required.

I'm happy to replace my binding with a custom binding as I control both sides and they are both .net but I've been unable to figure out how to create any custom binding that supports websockets.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I kept trying tons of different things and here is what I finally came up with and it's working. :)

```
    <binding name="GZipMutualCertificateBinding" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807" requireClientCertificate="true" transferMode="Streamed">
        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" />
      </httpsTransport>
    </binding>
```

This was found by trial and error, please let me know if you see anything that looks out of place.  Thanks.